# Webpack loaders in layman terms

Tags: javascript, webpack

Am I correct in understanding that Webpack transforms everything you have into JS code only? So that even if you have CSS, it will be turn into JS (in a bundle) as long as you have the correct loader?

> Loaders can transform files from a different language like
>   CoffeeScript to JavaScript, or inline images as data URLs. Loaders
>   even allow you to do things like require() css files right in your
>   JavaScript!”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loaders won't convert `CSS` into `JavaScript` but it will allow you to import `CSS` files right from your `JavaScript` file. For e.g. you have components based application architecture and each component has it's own CSS, you can load css right from component's JS file.

#### Like this (in your app.js)

```
import styles from './app.css';
```

#### OR more generic

```
import './app.css';
```

### [From Official site](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#example)

> Loaders can transform files from a different language (like
>   TypeScript) to JavaScript, or inline images as data URLs. Loaders even
>   allow you to do things like import CSS files directly from your
>   JavaScript modules!

#### Example

> For example, you can use loaders to tell webpack to load a CSS file or
>   to convert TypeScript to JavaScript. To do this, you would start by
>   installing the loaders you need:

```
npm install --save-dev css-loader
npm install --save-dev ts-loader
```

And then instruct webpack to use the css-loader for every .css file and the ts-loader for all .ts files:

Comment: So instead of using a `link` tag, you can use loaders instead? And then when that specific JS that required the CSS gets executed as part of the bundle, the CSS will get executed then as well? Does the namespacing of the CSS come automatically when you use a loader? So that will cause the CSS rules to not accidentally mix with other CSS rules that might have the same class name?

Comment: CSS will be part of bundle.css, it's just when component is rendered appropriate css will apply. No namespaces you have to maintain. Same classes will conflict. So best practice is to use unique class for each component's root element and then writing CSS accordingly.

Comment: Yeah link tags are not needed more. Only you have to include bundle.css